# Turn python input into command

Tags: python

I am working on making my own shell but what I want it to do what the user input.

For Example:

```
while 1:
    c = input()
    do c
```

By do c I want it to then do the command that the person put in.

Any Ideas,

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What type of command are you talking about, python commands or shell commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3, on Python 2 you would use `raw_input` instead

```
while 1:
    c = input()
    exec(c)
```

**note** that you can't trust that people won't enter malicious code here

You may also want to wrap this in a `try`/`except` to print the traceback when an `Exception` occurs and continue the loop:

```
import traceback
while 1:
    try: 
        c = input()
        exec(c)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

## system

system() from os moduule executes a command supplied as an argument and returns the return code.

```
import os
cmd=raw_input()
os.system(cmd)
```

## popen

popen is used to create a subprocess.The advantage is that popen can be used to read the output of a command executed.

```
import os
cmd=raw_input()
l=os.popen(cmd)
print l.read()
```

Comment: I don't believe OP wants a shell command, rather OP wants Python code command